# Amazon AWS website location

Tags: amazon-web-services, maplibre-gl

I'm trying to add a layer to my AWS Amplify map to be displayed in an HTML map for others to use. I can't seem to grasp the concept of the 'GetMap' capability that was stated in the AWS documentation-this will enable me to add one of my GIS layers into the map (from a object in a S3 bucket- I created an API for it). Not sure where that line of code would go to apply the layer. The following is the code I have so far but it doesn't show the layer I wanted:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/maplibre-gl@3.x/dist/maplibre-gl.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <style>
      body { margin: 0; }
      #map { height: 100vh; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/maplibre-gl@3.x/dist/maplibre-gl.js"></script>
    <script>
      const apiKey = "v1.public.eyJqdGkiOiJkNWMzODQwMC0zMDVkLTQ0M2ItOTkyZC04OTA1NGVkMTkxYTEifVzsfIeXlIK7EherirvuF7Nhhfr1xn-kz5sNUi5LxK6Sl3-DOwUGA6l1rDwZS8tM2cIAAMIMjjGGvgdkkLiwPX8kZ5wwnYzvyKpvcCMWBPvlauvYB1TsUN6ntnRD3hfN-on94UyEZ2ePt7-DdnAdxXOPxhM1Ir_fWeT9gHcNlqrkiZ7Lup1GNmZfdRQ7sT8fqE503tIoBXZLmb3S3ee4KXaudL71yoEpsPAzWiLPXLSzqFDQD-HEP9BG_5vl1zPGJpJWmrS5mh0MaL0DIXO4nJBBtP0HsMWJB_C8wL9QEANORRdEkQdVtFdOq7RVOrugmIEQ4JQ7Hx7kjR0bdSSk-BA.ZWU0ZWIzMTktMWRhNi00Mzg0LTllMzYtNzlmMDU3MjRmYTkx";
      const mapName = "UtilityViewer";
      const region = "us-east-1";

      const map = new maplibregl.Map({
        container: "map",
        style: `https://maps.geo.${region}.amazonaws.com/maps/v0/maps/${mapName}/style-descriptor?key=${apiKey}`,
        center: [-123.115898, 49.295868],
        zoom: 11,
      });
      map.addControl(new maplibregl.NavigationControl(), "top-left");
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

all this results in is a ESRI basemap with only the toggle controls in the top left of the screen.

Comment: Your write "doesn't show the layer i wanted". Does it show some other layer? It shows nothing? Any errors in the browser debugger console or network section? Please edit your question and add more info.

Comment: all this results in is a ESRI basemap with only the toggle controls in the top left of the screen. I am really novel to AWS so any assistance would be appreciated. thanks!

Comment: Any errors in the browser debugger console or network section?

Comment: If I try map URL with all your parameters, I get message `"User is not authorized to access this resource with an explicit deny"`. This means you have problem with authorization/authentication for your map source.

Comment: See more about MapLibre and AWS authentication here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/location/latest/developerguide/tutorial-maplibre-gl-js.html

Comment: Ok i changed the name in that source file for privacy concerns. I will check out that document-thanks!

Comment: But can i do that-reference the object in the code from an AWS bucket?